# Faking a service does not work. It calls the actual implementation of the service instead

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, fakeiteasy

I am faking a service using FakeItEasy

```cs
string phone = "123456";
var response = new VerifyResponse();
var fakeVerifyService = A.Fake<IVerifyService>();

var verifyCall = A.CallTo(() => fakeVerifyService.Verify(
                A<string>._,
                An<VerifyRequest>._));
//act
verifyCall.Returns(Task.FromResult(response ));
var result = await this.TestSubject.Handle(new VerifyPhoneCommand(phone), CancellationToken.None);
verifyCall.MustHaveHappened();
```

The problem here is that the implementation of `IVerifyService.Verify` is being called in the SUT method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You define `fakeVerifyService` but used `fakeVerificationService` in the lambda. Is that correct?

Comment: it’s a mistake i have corrected.

Comment: The code does not show `fakeVerifyService` being provided to `this.TestSubject`. I suspect you are not using `fakeVerifyService` in your test subject.